# VB6 Included Tick Mark in XMLHttp request

Tags: vb6, xmlhttprequest

I am working on some http requests and have hit a problem, one of the requests uses a tick mark (or "check mark") in the post params and I am struggling in VB6 to create it, it is a JSON post via Xmlhttp :

```
{"utf8":"✓","
```

When I try to create the post query I am unable to send this character as VB6 see's it as a question mark, hence it does not know what the character is.

Just wondered if anybody has come across this and managed to resolve it ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Potman

Answer (score 3):

As its JSON the simplest way is to use the JavaScript escape sequence for that Unicode codepoint:

```
{"utf8":"\u2713", ...
```

Alternatively in VB6 `ChrW$(&H2713)` will return this character.

(It will still likely display as `?` in the IDE but if you concatenate it to a string and send it via XMLHttp it should work)

Comment: Thanks for the Info Alex K, I will give it a try ,